# How can I create a map of the characters of a string and the number of their occurances in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a string `"Hello World"`

I need a `Map<Char, Int>` which will contain the pairs of each character and the number of times it appears in the string : `{H=1, e=1, l=3, o=2,r=1, d=1}`

How can I do that without using the traditional for loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do it like this

```
val map = "Hello World".groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
```

`map` will be of type `Map<Char, Int>`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.